# YOLOv1 and YOLOv2 -- Pr(Object) and "responsible" boxes

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

In the [YOLOv1 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf), Pr(Object) denotes the probability that there is an object in a certain grid cell.

1. When it comes to the ground truth values, which values can Pr(Object) take? Only 0 and 1?
2. What is the precise definition of "there is/appears an object" in a cell? Does an object appear in a cell if the center of its ground truth bounding box is in a cell?
3. How many anchor boxes are "responsible" for predicting a ground truth bounding box in [YOLOv2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242.pdf)? Only one like in YOLOv1 (the one with the highest IoU with the ground truth bounding box)?